# SOLR sort by score syntax

Tags: solr

My solr webrequest looks like this

> http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:8080/search/select?q=bay
>   cities&defType=dismax&qf=screenname^10+screenname1^100.0+comments^50+tagwords^10+spottype^40+spotscene^50+spotscenecategory^50&bq=locationid:22878^40&mm=1&start=0&rows=40reccount
>   desc&fq=locationid:22878 OR
>   *query*:"{!bbox}"&sfield=location&pt=34.0194543, -118.4911912&d=8&fl=profileid,screenname1,reccount,score,locationid&sort=score
>   desc

Here i am using &sort=score desc

Now iam looking like   `@sort=sum(log(popularity),score) desc`

But i use like this its giving me error

sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: sum(log(popularity),score)

Answer (score 3):

The issue, I think, is that `score` is a pseudofield and not a field that is actually indexed. Maybe you can try to use Relevance Functions in place of `score` (if you're using Solr 4.0). However, I think what you're trying to do is to **boost** the score based on `popularity`. In that case you'll want to look here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,
I fixed this using this:

> &sort=score desc, sum(log(popularity))

Comment: This has nothing todo with the question asked.
You are sorting by score as the first column, if two results have the same score then the second column is used. Also, the "sum" function you are using should have more than one variable.